# OPC DA / OpenOPC timeout errror when reading value twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, opc-da, open-opc

I am trying to execute the following python code:

```
import OpenOPC
import pywintypes

pywintypes.datetime = pywintypes.TimeType
opc = OpenOPC.client()

opc.connect('server_name')

value = opc['tag_name']
print(value)

opc['tag_name'] = value + 1

value = opc['tag_name'] # Timeout for the following line
print(value)

opc.close()
```

The code does work without the commented line of code reading the tag for the second time. However, the current code gives the timeout error:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 15
     11 print(value)
     13 opc['tag_name'] = value + 1
---> 15 value = opc['tag_name']
     16 print(value)
     18 opc.close()

File c:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.0-win32\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC\opcda.py:262, in client.__getitem__(self, key)
    260 def __getitem__(self, key):
    261     if self.win32os:
--> 262         return self.clientIO.__getitem__(self._opc, self.clientTools, key)
    263     else:
    264         return None

File c:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.0-win32\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC\opcdaio.py:660, in ClientIO.__getitem__(self, _opc, clientTools, key)
    658 def __getitem__(self, _opc, clientTools, key):
    659     """Read single item (tag as dictionary key)"""
--> 660     value, quality, time_str = self.read(_opc, clientTools, key)
    661     return value

File c:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.0-win32\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC\opcdaio.py:387, in ClientIO.read(self, _opc, clientTools, tags, group, size, pause, source, update, timeout, sync, include_error, rebuild)
    384     results = self.iread(_opc, clientTools, tags, group, size, pause, source, update, timeout, sync, include_error, rebuild)
    386 if single:
--> 387     return list(results)[0]
    388 else:
    389     return list(results)

File c:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.0-win32\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC\opcdaio.py:307, in ClientIO.iread(self, _opc, clientTools, tags, group, size, pause, source, update, timeout, sync, include_error, rebuild)
    305 now = time.time() * 1000
    306 if now - start > timeout:
--> 307     raise TimeoutError('Callback: Timeout waiting for data')
    309 if self.callback_queue.empty():
    310     pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()

Exception: ('TimeoutError', 'Callback: Timeout waiting for data')
```

**Why am I unable to read from the server multiple times?**

Some notes:

1. I am on windows, using 32 bit Python v 3.9.0
2. pip install pywin32 --upgrade, gives Requirement already satsisfied
3. I am able to write to server multiple times just fine
4. I am using OpenOPC: https://pypi.org/project/OpenOPC-DA/
5. I am able to read multiple time by using this very hacky solution:

Hacky solution:

```
import OpenOPC
import pywintypes

pywintypes.datetime = pywintypes.TimeType
opc = OpenOPC.client()

opc.connect('server_name')

value = opc['tag_name']
print(value)

opc['tag_name'] = value + 1

opc.close()
opc = OpenOPC.client()
opc.connect('server_name')
value = opc['tag_name']
print(value)

opc.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use OpenOPC-WF instead of OpenOPC-DA.

To solve, run in terminal:

1. pip uninstall OpenOPC-DA
2. pip install OpenOPC-WF